# Is there a word "dramaticness"?

Tags: word-usage, suffixes, is-it-a-word

I want to write the following:

This is due to the **dramaticness** of the day.

What other word can I use?

Comment: In what context: A revolution? A love affair? Contextless questions are very difficult to answer.

Comment: @lambie **dramaticness** is not a word in any context ...

Comment: Oh really? I would never ever have dreamt it was. [sarcasm]. Be that as it may, to try and help, one needs some context. There's a guy who works for the BBC called Gramaticus. Love that name.

Comment: I'm guessing your meaning is along the lines assumed by the answers already given. But are you saying the day itself is dramatic? (Like a dramatic sunrise, or dramatic weather throughout the day.) Or are you saying a lot of people acted dramatically today? (Which is what everyone assumes you meant.) I don't think it would really affect which "drama"-based word you'd use, but it could affect the way you use it.

Comment: Or maybe.... you know... “This was due to how dramatic the day was.” Or “This was due to the drama of the day.” Sometimes it just needs some restructuring, not a brand new word.

Comment: Dramatic is already an adjective. You can't describe how "howy" the day was. You must either return to the root word, or instead say that the day was similar to an established noun. If the majority doesn't agree (and maybe even then), this could be perceived as harassment; e.g. "This is due to the ignorance/conservatism/activism/politicization/romanticization today." To get away with it, it had better be a current and astute observation. I prefer the root word - or to rephrase, not to express yourself carefully at all, but to ensure you say exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The root word **drama** fits: "This is due to the *drama* of the day."

> **Drama**
>   3 a :  a state, situation, or series of events involving interesting or intense conflict of forces
>   b :  dramatic state, effect, or quality - *the drama of the courtroom proceedings* - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drama)

Answer (score 9):

It isn't in any official dictionary, though it does appear on community dictionaries like Urban Dictionary and Wordnik.

Merriam-Webster offers **dramatism** as the appropriate word to mean dramatic manner or form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply: Is it correct to write, This is due to the dramatism of the day?

Comment: That's how I would write it, yeah.

Comment: It also has just a couple of examples in the OED - the most recent being 1901. But I don't see the point. *Drama* gives better effect in my view. Some people have a dreadful tendency to create long words for things where thee is a perfectly good short one - (what is *the quietness* if not *the quiet*).

Comment: You mean there are people who will use verbose terminology when a diminutive vocabulary would suffice? :)

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire I know that; I didn't bother as it was just a stupid joke comment. And I didn't do it with my first comment as there was only one prior to it and I assumed OP was still checking the post.

Comment: I actually prefer *dramatism* to *drama*. Definitions *a* and *b* in @Lawrence's answer are clearly different: the actual dramatic events that take place vs. the abstract quality of being dramatic. *Dramatism* allows us to make that distinction clear when it might not otherwise be clear from context alone.

Comment: dramatism of the day? Seriously?? Drama or dramatic nature...

Comment: I would agree that *dramatism* doesn't fit the meaning in the OP's phrase very well. *The drama of the day* makes more sense. I think *dramatism* applies more to a person who is behaving dramatically. But I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Honestly I prefer drama as well; I just didn't think of it at the time.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to describe how people would overreact, then "melodrama", "histrionics", "theatricality" or even [*dramatics*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dramatic) might be close, instead of "drama". Which one you use depends on the context around your line - if you're referring to a society or large group of people, the above words fit better. If you're describing a situation between a few people, "drama" fits perfectly.

Also check out this SE question: [Is there a single word for a person who overreacts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121327/is-there-a-single-word-for-a-person-who-overreacts)